# Android: How to optimize ListView with ImageView + 3 TextViews?

Tags: android

I've been looking everywhere to see if there is a standard way of achieving this but I find a different solution every-time.

Basically, I am trying to build a `Custom ListView` with an image and two-three lines of text besides it.

In order to optimize it, I understand that the following have to be used:

1. `convertView`: Basically if the view was already inflated, use it
2. `Lazy-Loading`: Do not load the content of the rows until they are called for
3. Background `Downloading & Caching`: Download images in their own threads and then update the row (and possible cache them?)

I could manage 1 and 2 but the third one is really confusing me.

Is there a best practice for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Mark for his help. This is one way of doing what he suggested (just in case some else is curious):

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Bitmap> {

            private ImageView iv;

            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
                try {
                    iv = (ImageView) params[0];
                    URL aURL = new URL("http://URLTOIMAGE/img" + params[1] + ".png" ); 
                    URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection(); 
                    conn.connect(); 
                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream(); 
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is); 
                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis); 
                    bis.close(); 
                    is.close();
                    return bm;
               } catch (IOException e) { 
                    return null;
               } 
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                iv.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) result);
            }
        }
```

And it would be used as follows:

```
new DownloadImageTask().execute(new Object[] {ImageViewHandle, position});
```

Note that this is not a working code. This was taken from a larger code base so you will have to make appropriate changes to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit early to describe something as "best practice". `AsyncTask` or a thread monitoring a `LinkedBlockingQueue` are fine ways to offload something like image fetching.

You may be interested in my [`ThumbnailAdapter`](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-thumbnail), which handles the background downloading and caching for you.

Comment: As always, thanks for the simple answer. Thanks for pointing me to the ThumbnailAdapter. I am not quite familiar with your original AdapterWrapper class so I will go through that first before jumping into this code. As a matter of curiosity, if I am using AsynTask, who updates the ImageView? Does the thread get a handle to the ImageView or does it return a Bitmap which I use to update?

Thanks

Comment: AsyncTask#onPostExecute() is run on the UI thread. It can be passed the results of your download (from AsyncTask#doInBackground()), and it can update the appropriate ImageView.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for your input. I'll now implement a simple Caching mechanism. (Your Thumbnail adapter is of great help! Thanks a ton!). And by the way, I just got the AsynTask appraoch you suggested to work. I will post it as a response to this post.