# ListView scrolling using UniversalImageDownloader not smooth

Tags: android, android-listview, lag, smooth-scrolling, universal-image-loader

I am using a ListView containing images. These images are loaded from the Internet inside the adapter. Therefore I am using the **UniversalImageDownloader**.

Unfortunately the scrolling of the ListView "lags" for a short time as soon as I scroll down where new content has to be downloaded.

I acutally expected behaviour like the ListView scrolls perfectly smooth, but the loading of the Image can of course take some more time - which should not effect the smoothness of scrolling.

Furthermore, as I scroll back up the lags occur as well. It seems as if the images are not cached properly.

**Maybe my ImageLoader options are setup wrong?**

**Am I doing something wrong in my adapter?**

**The ListView contains about 20-30 Images with sizes 640x320 (around 150kb)**

Below you can see my Adapter as well as the ImageLoader.
(The class Downloader is just a wrapper class for the UniversalImageDownloader)

```
public class Downloader {

    /**
     * initializes the imagedownloader with a specific configuration
     * I CALL THIS METHOD RIGHT AFTER APP STARTUP
     * @param c
     */
    public static void initialize(Context c) {

         // Create global configuration and initialize ImageLoader with this configuration

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(c)
        .threadPoolSize(20) 
        .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY) // default
        .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO) // default
        .memoryCacheSize(20 * 1024 * 1024)
        .memoryCacheSizePercentage(15) // default
        .discCacheSize(20 * 1024 * 1024)
        .discCacheFileCount(100)
        .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator()) // default
        .imageDecoder(new BaseImageDecoder()) // default
        .build();

        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    }

    /**
     * gets the display options that are needed when displaying an image
     * @return
     */
    public static DisplayImageOptions getDisplayOptions() {

         DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.error)
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.error)
        .resetViewBeforeLoading(false)  // default
        .cacheInMemory(true) // default
        .cacheOnDisc(true) // default
        .build();

        return options;
    }

    public static ImageLoader getInstance() {
        return ImageLoader.getInstance();
    }
}
```

And the adapter:

```
public class EventListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Event> {

    private List<Event> mList;
    private DisplayImageOptions options;

    public EventListAdapter(Context context, int list_item_resource, List<Event> objects) {
        super(context, list_item_resource, objects);
        mList = objects;

        options = Downloader.getDisplayOptions();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Event event = mList.get(position);

        // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unneccessary calls to findViewById() on each row.
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.normalevent_list_item, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();;

            holder.eventimage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivEventImage);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }

        if (event != null) {

            holder.eventimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading);
            // Load image, decode it to Bitmap and display Bitmap in ImageView
            Downloader.getInstance().displayImage(event.getImageOneURL(), holder.eventimage, options);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {   

        ImageView eventimage;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue with image downloading. I solved it by setting delayBeforeLoading(1000) in my DisplayImageOptions. It is needed to start downloading when user stop fling.

so try to replace your getDisplayOptions method with this

```
 public static DisplayImageOptions getDisplayOptions() {

     DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.error)
    .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.error)
    .delayBeforeLoading(1000) 
    .resetViewBeforeLoading(false)  // default
    .cacheInMemory(true) // default
    .cacheOnDisc(true) // default
    .build();

    return options;
}
```

Documentation also recommends to use this code to avoid grid/list view scroll lags

```
boolean pauseOnScroll = false; // or true
boolean pauseOnFling = true; // or false
PauseOnScrollListener listener = new PauseOnScrollListener(imageLoader, pauseOnScroll, pauseOnFling);
listView.setOnScrollListener(listener);
```

You can read it [here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#useful-info) (the last item of "Useful Info" list)

So you can use one of this methods

Comment: And the lags are gone, thank you very much! :) PS: I set it to 100ms

Comment: what is imageLoader on PauseOnScrollListener Constructor ?

Answer (score 1):

@Sergey Pekar: You saved my life! :)
I always used UIL for ListView for a small count of images, but then as the count got bigger I got always a lag on the first load (while scrolling) of the images. 
So I also tried the delay and it helped a little bit and other UIL configs and options, but I was not happy.
Then I've tried different Image-Loading-Libraries (Picasso, AQuery, Volley, UrlImageViewHelper, custom code). They all worked faster(on first load) than UIL but they did not have enough options for me.
So I looked for the last 2 days for a solution regarding this lag-problem and thanx god I finally found your post here!
The solution was the PauseOnScrollListener!

What also (addtionally to the PauseOnScrollListener) improves a little bit the scroll-smoothness is by extending the ImageView to stop requestLayout like this:

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView
{
    public CustomImageView (Context context, AttributeSet attributeset, int int_style)
    {
        super(context, attributeset, int_style);
    }

    public CustomImageView (Context context, AttributeSet attributeset)
    {
        super(context, attributeset);
    }

    public CustomImageView (Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void requestLayout() 
    {
        // Do nothing here
    }
}
```

For more info see this post:
[ListView very slow when scrolling (using ViewHolder/recycling)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224244/listview-very-slow-when-scrolling-using-viewholder-recycling)

Comment: you saved my life! Its been a week. I tried all the available libraries(more than 10). But my listview was very sluggish while flinging. I also tried with PauseOnScrollListener of UIL. But your CustomImageView did the trick. Now my list is as fast as Wind :)

Comment: So I used same combo. UIL with this CustomImageView

Comment: Nice to hear Seshu :)