# Which Android image library for online photo loading

Tags: android, image, grid, photo

I want to make an application which loads image urls from my site (returned in a JSONArray) and then display the images in a gridview (the photos are also online, so needs to be loaded).

The problem is that I am confused which library is easier to use and has better performance?

Android Query or Android Universal Image Loader (UIL) ?

Comment: not sure why a good question is marked as off-topic :-(

Comment: You can find a lot of useful libraries here: http://android-arsenal.com Please, check sections "Networking" and "Image Loaders"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Android Universal Image Loader](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=6rcGU8nyN9SMkAeFy4GIBw&url=https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNGgmKC8hBtbywLST53tMmNnUAuNQA&sig2=5GhdR9IPi61oAxgws9Cn1Q) works like a champ.

It's very easy to use [here](http://sunil-android.blogspot.com/2013/09/lazy-loading-image-download-from.html?m=1) is an example

But, basically this is the way to use it with a `GridView`:

After the expected `imports`, you should:

```
protected AbsListView list;

protected ImageLoader loader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

private String query;

final Context context = this;

private ItemAdapter adapter;

private DisplayImageOptions op;

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 op = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
         .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))
         .build();

 list = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridViewSearch);
 adapter = new ItemAdapter(images);
 list.setAdapter(adapter);
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       // Do whatever you need to do after clicking an image.
     }
 });
}
```

And, of course you need the `adapter`:

```
class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

 private String[] imagesA;

 public ItemAdapter(String [] Images){
     this.imagesA = Images;
 }

 public void setData(String [] Images){
     this.imagesA = Images;
 }

 private class ViewHolder {
     public ImageView image;
 }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
     return imagesA.length;
 }

 @Override
 public Object getItem(int position) {
     return position;
 }

 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
     return position;
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     View v = convertView;
     v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.image_in_gridview_layout, parent, false);
     final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.loading);
     final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
     holder.image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
     v.setTag(holder);

     loader.displayImage(imagesA[position], holder.image, op, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
         @Override
         public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
             spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         }

         @Override
         public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
             spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         }

         @Override
         public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
             spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         }
     });

     return v;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

**[Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)** is the most popular one out there currently. Highly customizable, [tuto](http://sunil-android.blogspot.com/2013/09/lazy-loading-image-download-from.html).

**AQuery**; like jquery, but for Android? I guess it's nice, if you're into that sort of thing. Don't use this one though; it craps on the UI thread or something. Loading a bunch of images on my Nexus 4 in a listview made it seem like I was back on my HTC G1 all over again. Major stuttering, [tuto](http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/04/AQuery).

More:

**[Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)** has the nicest image API. I am going to steal their currying API style for my future/current stuff. Picasso is also noticeably the slowest. Especially on 3g vs wifi. Probably due to their custom okhttp client, [tuto](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

**[UrlImageViewHelper](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper) + [AndroidAsync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync)** is the fastest. Playing with these other two great libraries have really highlighted that the image API is quite dated, however.

**[Volley](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley)** is slick; I really enjoy their pluggable backend transports, and may end up dropping AndroidAsync in there. The request priority and cancellation management is great, [Google I/O 2013 presentation](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728), [tuto](http://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/raymond-robinson/google-io-2013-volley-image-cache-tutorial).

***I** recommend for you to make choice between Volley and Picasso*

Comment: this is android query, to me it seems very fast...https://code.google.com/p/android-query/

Comment: You should try the other ones if you don't yet and share your review here :)

Comment: so Volley is created by google, i think they use it in play store images loading.

Comment: And listen 2 minutes here from google: http://youtu.be/yhv8l9F44qo?t=28m33s

Comment: Volley seems fast, but I don't like it, very few features and somewhat low level...Android Query is fast too and much easier to use. I still want to choose between AQuery and UIL

Comment: than use UIL better i guarantee it's better than AQuery according to my bad experience using it :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Ion https://github.com/koush/ion or Picasso by square http://square.github.io/picasso/ ,both are great !

Answer (score 2):

Picasso (By Square) is very helpful and easy to use: http://square.github.io/picasso/

You should look into it.

Answer (score 2):

For me: Picasso is the way to go!

Why?

- Very fast
- Stable
- Easy to use
- Mostly one line of code

I used to use Universal ImageLoader 1.9.0 (UIL), till I had to use a ListView with an OnScrollListener, where the next 10 items where downloaded and the scrolling became not fluently enough with UIL while FAST-scrolling back and forth with, for example, 50 items loaded.
To accomplish a smooth scrolling, I've tried different configurations and options in UIL(did not help, except the delay option a bit) and I've tried AQuery(fast, but on scroll images vanished and appeared again even with a placeholder set) and UrlImageViewHelper(fast, but I could not set a drawable as a placeholder in case of "No Network Connection"), so I ended up with Picasso (the fastest from those four I've tested, hence a smooth scrolling) :)

But I have to give a big compliment to NOSTRA13 (creator of UIL) anyway because of:

- Clean and easy-to-follow documentation
- Easy to use
- Many options
- Stable
- Reliable support

Testing Environment:
Android HTC Desire X and a very weak Wifi-Connection.

**EDIT:**
I'm taking it back that other image-load-libs are faster: UIL is now for me the champ too! :)
I had always a scroll-lag with UIL on first load of the images and I knew it has something to do with the scrolling, so I was searching the net for more info till I found this beautiful post:
[ListView scrolling using UniversalImageDownloader not smooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187557/listview-scrolling-using-universalimagedownloader-not-smooth)
So I set the PauseOnScrollListener and see there, problem solved!
Hence: UIL is number 1!